# Installation Of ruby on rails in ubuntu14.04

Tags: software-installation, ruby, rails

How to install ruby on rails on Ubuntu 14.04? Which versions are better to install, and how to install

- ruby (version)
- rubygems,
- rubygems_update -v (version),
- mysql_server
- libmysqlclient-dev
- mysql2,
- rails -v=(version),
- rake --version (version),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install MySQL server, use the following command:

```
apt-get install mysql-server
```

More information on how to install ruby on rails on an Ubuntu server you can find at: http://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-ruby-2-0-and-rubygems-2-1-11-on-ubuntu-13-10-from-source/

To install the latest versions of Ruby and Rubygems download the following archives:

```
cd /root
wget http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/ruby-2.1.2.tar.gz
wget http://production.cf.rubygems.org/rubygems/rubygems-2.2.2.tgz
```

and execute the following commands:

```
tar xvzf ruby-2.1.2.tar.gz
cd ruby-2.1.2
./configure
make
make install
cd /root
tar xvzf rubygems-2.2.2.tgz
cd rubygems-2.2.2
ruby setup.rb
```

then, follow the tutorial above in order to install the latest gem versions etc.